# I have to post select options on change with PHP, but select is being converted to ul li by JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css, select, drop-down-menu

I am using styled select dropdown, from [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/):

I want to post the selected option in order to render some data for other dropdowns.

The problem is the the

```
 onChange="this.form.submit()"
```

is not working, as the JQuery changes select options to `ul > li`...
Any solution will be appericiated..
Either to post on the same,
or to have an alternative JQuery select which does not convert select to ul li.

> select name="districtid" id="districtid" class="cd-select" > onChange="this.form.submit();" >
>
> ```
>                    <option value="" selected>Select District</option>
>                   <?php do {
>                   ?>
>                   <option value="<?php echo >$row_district['id'];?>"
>                       <?php
>                   if(isset($_GET['districtid']))
> ```
>
> {
>   $pdistrict = $_GET['districtid']; 
>                                  if ($row_district['id'] == $pdistrict ) echo "selected";} 
>                             ?>>
>
> ```
>                       echo $row_district['name']; 
>
>                        ?>
>                    </option>
>
>                    <?php } while ($row_district = >mysql_fetch_assoc($district)); ?>
> ```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: yes.... edited with code..
This select option is surrounded by form
 <form method="get">code</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

from `line 143-151` in `jquery.dropdown.js`
update with the below code where `myform` is your `form's id`..
but it will not preserve the `dropdown` state as the page will load and if you want to preserve the drop down value as selected then you can use `cookie`.

```
this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
            if( self.opened ) {
                var opt = $( this );
                self.options.onOptionSelect( opt );
                self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );
                self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
                if ($("#myform").length == 1) {
                $("#myform").submit();//submitting myform
                }
                self.close();
            }
        } );
```

Comment: This is just awesome... It did the work..
many thanks for this....
can you tell me one thing, 
what $("#myform").length == 1 means ?

Comment: @Fahad you may tick it as right answer if it solved your issue :).